# How to get style props suggestions with react native typescript re-usable component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a text re-usable component coded like this :

```
import React, {FC, ReactNode} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text as RNText} from 'react-native';

interface TextProps {
  style?: any;
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
}

const Text: FC<TextProps> = ({style, children}) => {
  return <RNText style={{...styles.text, ...style}}>{children}</RNText>;
};

export default Text;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: colors.black,
    fontFamily: fonts.light,
  },
});
```

So every time I want to style it I don't get any prop suggestions for styling a react native text component :

[image]

How can I get all react native styles props suggestions for a custom re-usable made component with typescript ?

Comment: There are many similar questions, are you asking how to get the style type? Did you try something like `import { TextStyle, ViewStyle } from "react-native";` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use StyleProp, look at the code below:

```
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleProp,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ViewStyle,
  TextStyle
} from 'react-native';

interface LazyLoadImageType {
  imgUri: string;
  onLoadEnd?: () => void;
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  // or
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  // or
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle | TextStyle>;

}
```

Comment: What is the use of StyleProp If I may ask ?

Comment: you can compare it with "foo=[]: Array<number|string>" here "Array" is a general type of the foo variable that is an array, so styleProp is also the general type for style attribute and by using viewStyle | testStyle you define which types of styles have to include in your type